# There is no assemble option in Android Studio - Gradle panel

Tags: android-studio, gradle, assemble

(1) I am trying to build an Android source project by using Gradle - assemble.

(2) Other developers in my team said there is assemble option in Android Studio - Gradle panel.
But in my environment there is no assemble option.

(3) I am using Android Studio 2022.1.1 Patch 1 version and MacBook M1 pro chip.
And Gradle Plugin version is 7.1.2. I tried to upgrade it, but failed.

How can I fix this issue? (Not showing assemble option in Gradle panel)

[image: Screen shot of Android Studio version & Gradle panel]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Uncheck - 'Do not build Gradle task ~' in Experimental of Preferences.